# Render a link from a FieldPluginBase

Tags: views, 8, entities

I created a custom view field with the hook _views_data and a custom Class who extends FieldPluginBase.

With the render method, I can return a sample string :

```
class MyCustomClassViewsField extends FieldPluginBase {
...
    public function render(ResultRow $values) {
      $node = $values->_entity;
      return $node->id(); // My view field shows the nid of the current node
    }
...
```

Now, I want shows a link with my field. I tried :

```
class MyCustomClassViewsField extends FieldPluginBase {
...
    public function render(ResultRow $values) {
      $node = $values->_entity;
      return "<a href='http://www.test.com'>custom link</a>"
    }
...
```

But my field in my view shows :

```
<a href='http://www.test.com'>custom link</a>
```

and not

[custom link](http://www.test.com)

How can I show the link as an html element, not a sample text ?

Thank you =)

**UP**

This code work :

```
return array('#markup' => \Drupal::l("test",\Drupal\Core\Url::fromUri("http://www.example.com")));
```

ut the l() function is deprecated. If I use Link::fromTextAndUrl instead :

```
return array('#markup' => \Drupal\Core\Link::fromTextAndUrl("test",\Drupal\Core\Url::fromUri("http://www.example.com")));
```

I get the error :

> [Sun Sep 18 22:17:59.444188 2016] [:error] [pid 2143] [client
>   192.168.1.48:53322] Recoverable fatal error: Object of class Drupal\Core\Link could not be converted to string in
>   /var/www/xxxxx/core/lib/Drupal/Component/Utility/Xss.php
>   on line 67, referer:
>   https://192.168.1.45/admin/structure/views/view/customview
>
> [Sun Sep 18 22:17:59.446098 2016] [:error] [pid 2143] [client
>   192.168.1.48:53322] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get() on null in
>   /var/www/xxxxx/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Session/SessionHandler.php:76\nStack
>   trace:\n#0
>   /var/www/xxxxx/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Session/Storage/Handler/WriteCheckSessionHandler.php(89):
>   Drupal\Core\Session\SessionHandler->write('BTaHaVF0t-bMk2Z...',
>   '_sf2_attributes...')\n#1
>   /var/www/xxxxx/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Session/WriteSafeSessionHandler.php(75):
>   Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\WriteCheckSessionHandler->write('BTaHaVF0t-bMk2Z...',
>   '_sf2_attributes...')\n#2
>   /var/www/xxxxx/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Session/Storage/Proxy/SessionHandlerProxy.php(77):
>   Drupal\Core\Session\WriteSafeSessionHandler->write('BTaHaVF0t-bMk2Z...',
>   '_sf2_attributes...')\n#3 [internal function]:
>   Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Proxy\SessionHandlerProxy->write('BTaHaVF0t-bMk2Z...',
>   '_sf2_attributes...')\n#4 [internal function]:
>   session_write_close()\n#5 {main}\n  thrown in
>   /var/www/xxxxx/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Session/SessionHandler.php
>   on line 76, referer:
>   https://1xxxxx/admin/structure/views/view/customview

How can I replace the l deprecated function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert array to string to show it as link. May this works for you.

```
class MyCustomClassViewsField extends FieldPluginBase {
...
    public function render(ResultRow $values) {
      $node = $values->_entity;
$title = 'Custom Link';
$url = \Drupal\Core\Url::fromUri('http://www.test.com');
$link = \Drupal\Core\Link::fromTextAndUrl($title, $url)->toString();

      return $link;
    }
```